# How to store and retrieve milliseconds in a date object in Java?

Tags: java, date

I'm making a basic Java program that reads in a subtitle (.srt) file and I would like to store each time as a Date object. I really only need to keep track of Hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds (to 3 digits). I think I am able to store it using this:

```
String start = "00:01:01,604";
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss,SSS");
Date startDate = sdf.parse(start);
```

For retrieving, I can do something like this:

```
return String.format("\nStart: %d:%d:%dText: %s\n", startDate.getHours(),startDate.getMinutes(), startDate.getSeconds(), text);
```

I'm looking for something that would do something similar to getMilliseconds (if it existed). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way to get access to part of date (hours,minutes, etc.) in Java is now using `Calendar.get(Calendar.MILISECONDS)`, see [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29). In case of your code it would look like this:

```
Date startDate = sdf.parse(start);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(startDate);
int milliseconds = calendar.get(Calendar.MILISECONDS);
```

P.S. Please note that regarding to [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getHours%28%29) `Date.getHours()`,`Date.getSeconds()`, etc. methods are currently deprecated anyway. Don't use them :).

Answer (score 5):

What you're handling is not a date! Don't use the `Date` class to handle it! Dates have strange extra rules that you don't care about and that could easily trip you up (just think of leap years, leap seconds and time zones).

You should *either*

- use a `long` to hold the milliseconds and handle the calculation on your own (it's not so hard, you're not implementing a calendar) *or*
- use an existing duration class such as [the one from Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_duration.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just call `date.getTime()` and get milliseconds.

Comment: getTime() returns the milliseconds since begin of epoch. OP wants milliseconds since last full second.

Comment: Generally, using `Date` for this is wrong. You'll either want to use a plain `long` or a dedicated duration class (such as [the one from Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_duration.html)).

Answer (score 1):

You can always use Date.getTime() for getting value in milliseconds. It will return a value in long format